# Count objects created of each type individually

Tags: java, generics

```
class Node<E> {
     private E data;
     private Node<E> next;
     Node(E data, Node<E> next) {
         this.data = data;
         this.next = next;
     }
     // .. getter-setters
}
```

To keep a count of how many objects of Node class are created, we can add a static attribute in the class and increment it whenever a new object is created.

How to keep a count of instances of Node created for EACH type ? 
(eg. 6 Node instances are of type Integer, 4 Nodes of type Float etc).

A naive approach can be to add static variables for each type (eg. IntCount, FloatCount) and increment it as per the instance of data passed to the constructor.

```
class Node<E> {
    private E data;
    private Node<E> next;
    private static int GlobalCount;
    private static int IntCount, FloatCount;

    static {
        GlobalCount = IntCount = FloatCount = 0;
    }

    Node(E data, Node<E> next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
        GlobalCount++;

        if(data instanceof Integer) 
            IntCount++;
        else if (data instanceof Float) 
            FloatCount++;
    }
}
```

Currently this will keep track of the counts only for Integer and Float. The above modification will not be a good solution if the the number of types to be traced increases.

I want to know if there is some better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have following `HashMap`

```
static HashMap<Class, Integer> refCount = new HashMap<Class, Integer>();

Node(E data, Node<E> next) 
{
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
    GlobalCount++;

    Class type = data.getClass();

    Integer countObj = refCount.get(type);
    int count = 1;
    if(countObj != null)
    {
        count = countObj.intValue();
        count++;
    }
    refCount.put(type, count); 
}
```

Comment: The HashMap should be made static

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the counter 'static'.

My data structure class...

```
public class LinkedList<T> {

private GenericNode<T> head;
private int size;    //Don't make this 'static'

public LinkedList(){
    this.head = null;
    size = 0;
}

public int size(){
    return size;
}
```

My application class...

```
private static LinkedList<Flight> scheduledFlights;
private static LinkedList<Passenger> outboundPassengers;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    scheduledFlights = new LinkedList<Flight>();
    outboundPassengers = new LinkedList<Passenger>();



    scheduledFlights.add(new Flight("EI123", "Aer Lingus", "CDG"));
    scheduledFlights.add(new Flight("EI223", "Aer Lingus", "STN"));

    outboundPassengers.add(new Passenger("John", "LHR", "London"));
    outboundPassengers.add(new Passenger("Paul", "LHR", "London"));
    outboundPassengers.add(new Passenger("George", "LHR", "London"));
    outboundPassengers.add(new Passenger("Ringo", "LHR", "London"));

    System.out.println(scheduledFlights.size());
    System.out.println(outboundPassengers.size());
```

And the console outputs...

```
2
4
```

Showing that the counters are specific to the instance of LinkedList.

Why... I appreciate that for a counter in an ordinary object class, you would use a static counter. The 'static' counter will be commonly referenced across all instances of your object and so all increments or decrements affect the same counter.

When you instantiate a Generics Class of whatever type, the 'static' variable is tied to the instances of `GenericsClass`, not `GenericsClass<anytype>`. So in my case, a `static int size` would be common int variable across all instances of LinkedList, regardless of if it was `LinkedList<Flight>` or `LinkedList<Passenger>`.

So it's correct to use a regular instance variable as a counter when using a Generics based Data structure.

Hope this helps.

John